# Data frame to 3D array and calculate mean in Z

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame read from CSV which contains 14 columns and 990 rows. Each set of 110 rows contains repeats of structured data (not the values) with the first 5 columns being labels.

I now want to create a new grid of 14x110, such that if columns are labelled with letters and rows are numbered numerically, then `A1` to `E110`  of the new grid are the labels and `F1` contains the mean average of `F1` in the original frame, and so on through to `N110`.

I have never used `R` before, and have got as far as calculating the mean of one cell with

```
mean(data[c(seq.int(3,nrow(d),110)),c(6)])
```

but I need some help with repeating this for the rest of the cells and constructing a resulting data frame, please.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an array of 14 columns 110 rows and 9 layers from a matrix of 14 columns and 990 rows?

Comment: Yes, and then calculate the mean across the layers for each cell

Comment: My answer below calculate the mean for each cell across layers. If you want the mean of each layer then `out=NULL` ,`for(i in 1:5){out[i]=mean(yourarray[,,i])}`.

Answer (score 0):

To transform an matrix to a 3D array

```
yourarray=array(unlist(yourmatrix),dim = c(110,14,9))
```

Then to take an average of z values you can do something like

```
out=matrix(NA,110,14)
for(n in 1:14){
for(i in 1:110){out[i,n]=mean(b[i,n,])}}
```

**Example**

```
a=matrix(1:125,25,5)
b=array(unlist(a),dim = c(5,5,5))
out=matrix(NA,5,5)
for(n in 1:5){
for(i in 1:5){out[i,n]=mean(b[i,n,])}}

> out
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   51   56   61   66   71
 [2,]   52   57   62   67   72
 [3,]   53   58   63   68   73
 [4,]   54   59   64   69   74
 [5,]   55   60   65   70   75
```

Hope this is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks! I just need to convert to array differently. I need to represent "pages" of data each of 110 rows from the original, stacked in the Z axis. So the first is rows 1..110, the second is rows 111..220, etc., rather than wrapping from the bottom of column n to the top of column n+1. How would I do that?

Comment: Ok so from what I'm gathering you just want to fill the array by rows and not by columns. Try `aperm`. Examine the difference between `aperm(array(c(1:125), c(5,5,5)),perm=c(2,1,3))` and just the array `array(c(1:125), c(5,5,5))`. We see that the command `perm` in `aperm` tells the array what dimensions to fill first, `perm=c(2,1,3)` means fill rows then columns then layers. You could probably also get what you want by making a series of transformations to your input matrix but I think aperm is a nicer way of doing things.